# Google Recaptcha not showing up in Formik/Netlify form

Tags: recaptcha, netlify, formik

I am trying to add Google Recaptcha to my Gatsby form and cannot see it. Seeing the following error in console: "reCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: onloadCallback"

I've followed the directions on Netlify for setting up the custom captcha: https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/

This, however, has not worked for me. I cannot see the Recaptcha.

In my form, I have:

1. In the form tag: 'data-netlify-recaptcha = true"
2. I have the div as specified in the Google Docs:

```
   <div className="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey={siteKey}
                  data-theme="dark"></div>
```

3. I have installed the gatsby-plugin-recaptcha in my gatsby-config.js as follows:

```
   {
   resolve: `gatsby-plugin-recaptcha`,
     options: {
       async: true,
       defer: false,
       args: `?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit`,
     }
  },
```

4. I am handling submit by submitting as a POST using Formik:

```
  fetch("/", {
              method: "POST",
              headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
              body: encode({"form-name": "contact", ...values}),
          })
          .then(() => alert("Your form has been received."));
```

I am not seeing what I am doing wrong. What can I do to display the captcha and have it work properly?

Comment: did this ever get resolved?